# Windows batch file: pathname with "&" interpreted as two commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which gets its own short pathname (to eliminate spaces, which gcc doesn't like) for use in subsequent commands:

```
set base=%~d0%~sp0
```

This works fine for most cases; for example, if the batch file is located in C:\Program Files, the value of %base% will be C:\PROGRA~1, and gcc is happy.

However, it doesn't work if the batch file is in a directory with "&" in the name. If it is in a directory called "C:\Here & There", the command above expands to

```
set base=C:\HERE&T~1\
```

which is treated as two commands, producing the error message `'T~1\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

If I put quotes around it:

```
set base="%~d0%~sp0"
```

Then the command works, and the value of %base% is `"C:\HERE&T~1\"` (including the quotes). But then the quotes break something else further on in the file when I use it to build a Java classpath:

```
java -cp .;"C:\HERE&T~1\"Jars\* foo
```

which says "The system cannot find the file specified" (relating to `"C:\HERE&T~1\"Jars\*` in the classpath).

Can anyone suggest a way around this Microsoft mess?

**[Edit]**

As requested by Mofi below, here is a minimal reproducible example batch file:

```
@echo off
set base=%~d0%~sp0
echo %base%
```

If this is executed in a directory called "C:\Here & There", I would like the output to be

```
C:\HERE&T~1
```

without quotes or other extraneous output.

Here is the actual output when using CMD.EXE as the shell:

```
'T~1\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\HERE
```

If I change the line `@echo off` to `@echo on` to show the commands as they are executed, I get this (where "C:\Here & There>" is the prompt, followed by the actual command being echoed prior to execution):

```
C:\Here & There> set base=C:\HERE  & T~1\
'T~1\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Here & There> echo C:\HERE
C:\HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems, the first is the expansion in the `SET` command.
It can be avoided by quotes around the expression.

```
set "base=%~dps0"
```

The second problem is the `echo`, it can be avoided by quotes, too.

```
echo "%base%"
```

But then the quotes are visible, too.
In a batch file, this can be solved with delayed expansion:

```
set "base=%~dps0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !base!
```

But on the command line, the delayed expansion mode can not be modified by `setlocal`, it can only be set by the `/v:on` option when `cmd.exe` starts

```
cmd /v:on
set "base=%~dps0"
echo !base!
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the quotes should not be part of the value, the correct SET command would be

```
set "base=%~d0%~sp0"
```